# Segmentation Fault: 11, Python 2.7.10, TensorFlow model

Tags: python-2.7, tensorflow, segmentation-fault, osx-elcapitan

I am running a TensorFlow model from the book ‘Tensorflow for Machine Intelligence’ on my terminal. However, when I run it I get a segmentation fault: 11.

The segmentation fault occurs whilst reading the .jpeg images from the dataset and writing them into a .tfrecords file. The program reads and writes 74 images before crashing.

What could be causing this?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: is it always the same file? if so, can you view it normally? what happens when you rename the 74th image so a different image is there instead.

Comment: @chris I have changed the name of the file and it always crashes on the 74th image regardless of the image. I can also view the image normally. Thanks, any other ideas why it might be crashing?